# How to divide specific elements in a list and then square the values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Given a list of positive integers, you have to find numbers divisible by 3 and replace them with their squares.

For example, consider the list below:

Input:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

The output for the above list would be:

```
[1,2,9,4,5,36]
```

Here is what I've worked on :

```
import ast,sys
input_str = sys.stdin.read()
input_list = ast.literal_eval(input_str)
myInt = 3
new_list = [x / myInt for x in input_list]

def square(input_list)
    if x/3:
        for x in input_list
        return x**2

print (square(input_list))
```

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: No, this is not homework. I'm looking to build an algo based on this pattern.

Comment: `x/3` does not test if `x` is divisible by `3`, it just divides and returns the result (always true). What you want is `x % 3 == 0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
list = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

for x in range(len(list)):
    if list[x] % 3 == 0: list[x] = list[x]**2

print(list)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
input = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
new_list = [number**2 if number % 3 == 0 else number for number in input]
```

output

```
[1, 2, 9, 4, 5, 36]
```

for a function:

```
def fun_sqrt(input_list, number, sqrt):

    new_list = [number**sqrt if number % number == 0 
                else number 
                for number in input_list
                ]

    return new_list
```

you can run by:

```
fun_sqrt(input_list, number=3, sqrt=2)
```

Comment: Can you tell me if we can write the same in a function?

Answer (score 0):

```
inputList = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
newList = []

for item in inputList:
    if item % 3 == 0:
        newList.append(item*item)
    else:
        newList.append(item)

print(newList)
```